# Assimp gltf2 exporter support for internal texture storage

Tags: assimp

Does the assimp gltf2 exporter support storing texture data inside the file? Specifically I am interested in the binary version of gltf2.

Answer (score 0):

Assimp supports storing textures in gltf files:

[Main page of assimp documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/index.html)

But unfortunately does not support glb.